# Angular: Render component from variable

Tags: angular, angular5

In my component, I have a list of components that I received via `@ContentChildren`. Now I want to render these components in my view, but I am stuck with how to do so. I experimented with `ng-container` and `ng-content`, but I had no success with them. I was thinking of something along the lines:

```
<component-renderer [component]="myComponent"></component-renderer>
```

But I have not found anything that offers this functionality. I put together a full (as minimal as I could) example to get the picture (maybe I already went wrong some step before?). It is also important that I get the reference to those components in my component, as they will all implement a specific interface that I want to use:

**MyInterface.ts**

```
import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";

export const MyInterfaceToken = new InjectionToken<MyInterface>('MyInterfaceToken');

// This interface will be implemented by the "child" components.
export interface MyInterface {
    doSomething(): void;
}
```

**simple.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MyInterface, MyInterfaceToken } from '../MyInterface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple',
  template: '<div>{{ value }}</div>',
  providers: [{
    provide: MyInterfaceToken, useExisting: SimpleComponent
  }]
})
export class SimpleComponent implements MyInterface {
  @Input() public value: string;

  doSomething(): void {
    alert(this.value);
  }
}
```

**multi-container.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Self, Inject, Optional, Directive, ContentChildren, AfterContentInit, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { MyInterface, MyInterfaceToken } from '../MyInterface';

// Directive to retreive the components, partially taken from:
// https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8277
@Directive({ selector: '[multi-container-item]' })
export class MultiContainerItemDirective {
  constructor(@Inject(MyInterfaceToken) @Self() @Optional() public component: MyInterface) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-multi-container',
  templateUrl: './multi-container.component.html'
})
export class MultiContainerComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(MultiContainerItemDirective) public items: QueryList<MultiContainerItemDirective>;

  public ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.items); // Inspect in console => got both items.
    this.items.first.component.doSomething(); // works.
  }

  public getComponents() {
    return this.items.map(x => x.component);
  }
}
```

**usage example**

```
<app-multi-container>
  <app-simple [value]="'Test1'" multi-container-item></app-simple>
  <app-simple [value]="'Test2'" multi-container-item></app-simple>
</app-multi-container>
```

To put the question short: What do I put into the html of multi-container to render the items? Something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let component of getComponents()">
  <component-renderer [component]="component"></component-renderer>
</div>
```

Comment: `forwardRef` here is redundant `forwardRef(() => SimpleComponent)`  - read here why [What is `forwardRef` in Angular and why we need it](https://blog.angularindepth.com/what-is-forwardref-in-angular-and-why-we-need-it-6ecefb417d48)

Comment: also `MultiContainerItemDirective` is redundant here, you could use `@ContentChildren(SimpleComponent) public items`. Now the question is why don't use simply use `ng-content` like this `<div <ng-content select="app-simple"></ng-content></div>`?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com thanks, you're right, I can remove `forwaredRef` and it still works - I will have a look at that article! For your second question: In the end, I don't know about `SimpleComponent` - I want to support just any component that implements the Interface.

Comment: I see, cool, right strategy :). So what about using `<div <ng-content select="app-simple"></ng-content></div>`?

Comment: Using `app-simple` as the selector in my view would (if I understand correclty) restrict the supported child components to be SimpleComponents. I want to support any component that implements the interface, as well as any combination of them. So the user of `multi-container` could just throw in a `SimpleComponent`, some `OtherComponent` and then again another `SimpleComponent`. The multi-container would render them (with some additional markup around each component) and also _do_ something with them (through the interface).

Comment: you can select by any selector, for example `multi-container-item`: `<div <ng-content select="multi-container-item"></ng-content></div>`, or drop `select` part entirely if you expect only `multi-container-item` to be used as content children

Comment: Wow, as simple as that! I need to use `select="[multi-container-item]"` because my directive is attribute-based (as I want to combine it with tag-based components), but your hint was exactly what I needed! I need some additional markup around each of those items, but I guess I will find some documentation about how to do that with `ng-content`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, if you put that as an answer, I will be happy to accept it. :)

Comment: posted :). check out the article I referenced and I'd recommend reading all articles on angularindepth.com - they are unique and in-depth

Comment: also wondering why you need this part `provide: MyInterfaceToken, useExisting: SimpleComponent`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159645/discussion-between-chips-100-and-angularindepth-com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `ng-content` in the `MultiContainerComponent` component:

```
<div><ng-content select="[multi-container-item]"></ng-content></div>
```

Comment: What about if you need to dynamically set which of the elements in ContentChildren to display? As opposed to a static class selector like this.